# Difference between using React-Redux <Provider> and connect()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am confused about why a create-react-app has both

```
import {store} from './our-redux-store'

const app = () => {

   return (
       <Provider store={store}>
          <WholeAppGoesHere/>
       </Provider>
   )
}
```

versus using connect with a component like so:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class MyComp {
   // ...
}

export default connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(MyComponent);
```

do we need both? what's the difference?

Comment: Provider is a wrapper for store, and connect function allows you to access and modify Provider's store. hard to tell the difference, since it is separate parts of the one thing.

Answer (score 1):

The provider is a component. You use the provider at the top of the component chain where your application starts.  You place it so it wraps your entire application.  Within this container, you pass the store.  This allows any child component to access the store.

connect() is used as a higher-order function that you wrap around specific components.  Connect in essence maps state data contained within the store to the props within that specific component.  Maybe it helps to think of connect() as a way an individual component gets the specific data it needs from the global store

Answer (score 0):

Provider is a part of [React Context functionality](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).  By assigning your store there, it makes the specific value of store available to all consumers of that context.

connect() on the otherhand is a higher order component that injects your mapped states and dispatches into the props of your base component.  To do so, it calls the Consumer part of this api to access the store context.

Edit: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#understanding-context-usage